# Connecting db2 using Oracle SQL Developer, with db2 having DATA_ENCRYPT

Tags: db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have imported the db2 jdbc into the awl developer and I can find the db2 tab. 
But I can't find any setting that can apply a securityMechanism into the connection string. 
So when I connect the db it kept prompting security mechanism not supported.
Is there any way I can apply the security mechanism to the connection, or if there is any way I can manually configure a jdbc connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DATA_ENCRYPT` setting is not something that you set up with the  `securityMechanism` property.  This is a server level setting, but it only applies to JDBC Type 2 drivers (i.e. using a JDBC URL of the form `jdbc:db2:YOURDB`).

That said, `DATA_ENCRYPT` uses a weak security mechanism, and many IBMers from the DB2 Development Lab have recommended strongly against relying on it.  SSL is the recommended security mechanism, so you really should talk to your DBA about enabling on your database server so you can use it with your java application.

Comment: May be my wordings has misleaded you. Actually I know this is a server level setting. So that I want to know is how to apply a securityMechanism property to the connection in sql developer, whatever the encrypt type is.

Comment: BTW, this is a intranet application so I don't care very much about the security level. But still thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You can't use DATA_ENCRYPT with the Type 4 connection. So you would need, install the full DB2 Data Server Client (if you don't have it already) and catalog your database from the client.  Then, use the JDBC URL `jdbc:db2:YOURDB`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Besides, is there any supported encrypt type which I don't need the full DB2 client?

Comment: For full data encryption (and not just username/password encryption during authentication) the only way is SSL.